# Check value of C #define with autoconf

Tags: c, autotools, autoconf

I know I can use [AC_CHECK_DECL / AC_CHECK_DECLS](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Generic-Declarations.html) to check whether a set of headers provides a declaration for a specified identifier, but how can I check not only whether a macro is declared, but also whether its expansion meets my criteria?  Specifically, I would like to check whether `numa.h` contains a macro definition equivalent to this ...

```
#define LIBNUMA_API_VERSION 2
```

... including the specific value "2".

**UPDATE**: 
`<numa.h>` header contains a definition such as `#define LIBNUMA_API_VERSION 2` to declare it's version. C code that uses this header typically uses it like so:

```
#if defined(LIBNUMA_API_VERSION) && LIBNUMA_API_VERSION >= 2
....
#endif
```

I want to determine NUMA header version with `autoconf`, and define a macro that succinctly conveys whether NUMA version 2 is provided. i.e.:

```
if test "$have_numa_v2" = "yes" ; then
    AC_DEFINE(NUMA_VERSION_2, 1, [Determine whether NUMA v2 available)
fi
```

That could be used like so:

```
#ifdef NUMA_VERSION_2
....
#endif
```

Is it possible?  I'm having trouble determining how I could set the value of variable `have_numa_v2` variable in my Autoconf file.

Comment: Check from where? From makefile? Shell script? C code?

Comment: The OP says from numa.h

Comment: As I understand it, this definition is part of numa.h. But maybe not.

Comment: @dbrank0 ah you are right :)

Comment: Maybe a combination of `AC_CHECK_HEADER()` and `AC_DEFINE()` will do what your are looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`AC_COMPILE_IFELSE`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Running-the-Compiler.html) or [`AC_RUN_IFELSE`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Runtime.html) with a suitably-structured test program to determine whether the macro is defined to a specific value you designate.  For example, supposing that the current language is C:

```
have_numa_v2=no
AC_RUN_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([
#include <numa.h>
],[
#if LIBNUMA_API_VERSION != 2
exit(1);
#endif
])], [have_numa_v2=yes])
```

That constructs a program whose return value depends on whether `LIBNUMA_API_VERSION` is defined as a macro, and if so, whether it expands to `2`.  If Autoconf cannot compile it (because, say, it cannot find numa.h) or if it exits with a status other than 0 then nothing else happens (`$have_numa_v2` retains its assigned value of `"no"`).  Otherwise, the assignment in the second argument is performed, and `$have_numa_v2` ends up with the value `"yes"`.

For what it's worth, the source of the particular test program produced and used by that macro contains some Autoconf-standard macro definitions, plus this:

```
#include <numa.h>

int
main ()
{

#if LIBNUMA_API_VERSION != 2
exit(1);
#endif

  ;
  return 0;
}
```

The version using AC_COMPILE_IFELSE would be similar, but built around using an `#error` preprocessor directive to make compilation fail if the macro is not defined to the specified value.  That variation might be a better choice if you anticipate any possibility that your program will be cross-compiled for a foreign architecture.